# Неправильно работает скрипт по выводу карты с игроком

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

```
import sys
playercords = [10, 10]
for a in range(10):
    for b in range(20):
        if(playercords[0] == a and playercords[1] == b):
            sys.stdout.write("A")
        else:
            sys.stdout.write("#")
    print("")
```

Нужно, чтобы в определённый момент вывелся символ A, но выводится только это:

```
####################
####################
####################
####################
####################
####################
####################
####################
####################
####################
```

Comment: playercords[0] == a - всегда ложно, как и второе. range(10) возвращает целые от 0 до 9 включительно

Comment: вообще то всё правильно. у вас проблема в первом цыкле: генерируется список от 0 до 9, 10 не включительно. либо увеличте генератор для первого цыкла, либо понизте первое число в playercords

Comment: `sys.stdout.write("A")` -> `print("A", end='')`, `print("")` -> `print()`, `if(playercords[0] == a and playercords[1] == b):` -> `if playercords[0] == a and playercords[1] == b:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если в вашем коде увеличить размер поля в строке `for a in range(11):` с 10 до 11, то игрок `A` появится:

```
####################
####################
####################
####################
####################
####################
####################
####################
####################
####################
##########A#########
```